# Sum of weak star closed set and compact weak star set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a real Banach space and $X^*$ be its dual space.
Let $C$ be a weak$^*$ closed subset in $X^*$ and $D$ a compact weak$^*$ in $X^*$.
I would like to ask whether $C+D$ is closed weak$^*$ in $X^*$.

Comment: More generally, in a topological group, compact times closed is closed.

Comment: @GEdgar you mean there is more general result (which you stated)?

Comment: @Norbert: See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{c_\alpha + d_\alpha\}$ be a net in $C+D$ with $c_\alpha + d_\alpha \to x$ (in the weak-* topology).  Passing to a subnet, we may assume $d_\alpha \to d$.  Then $c_\alpha \to x - d$, so since $C$ is closed, $x-d \in C$, which means $x = (x-d) + d \in C+D$.  Thus $C+D$ is indeed closed.

Following GEdgar's comment, the same proof shows that in any topological group, the product of a closed set with a compact set is closed.