# The definition of a closed function and its epigraph

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, closed-graph

There is a related discussion:
[closed epigraphs equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467441/closed-epigraphs-equivalence)
[Showing that projections $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221816/showing-that-projections-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr-are-not-closed)

My problem is rather simple:

A function is closed if its epigraph is closed.

For example:

1. $f(x) = x^2$ (also a convex function with its epigraph convex.)
2. $f(x) =  \tan^{−1} (x)$

However, I am confused about like the first case, the epigraph approaches infinity as $y\rightarrow \infty$. The second case, the epigraph approaches infinity as $x\rightarrow\infty$. The epigraph has no boundary on the right and left directions.

I cannot understand why their epigraph is closed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed set  definition says that: a set is closed when all the limit points of the set are in set. Now if you check even $R$ is a closed set. From this you can get an idea why the above sets(epigraphs of the function) are closed.